# Is MSE a good place for this question

Tags: support, allowed-questions, specific-question

I want to place a bounty on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/382479/6555) question, but I'm not sure if MSE is the best place for it. In general, where is the best place to ask that type of question. It seems that neural networks are generally more on-topic elsewhere, but from the [literature](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/089360809190009T) involved and the nature of the question, this particular question seems more purely mathematical than anything else.

Comment: I commented on your question that perhaps http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ or http://cs.stackexchange.com/ might be better suited for this question.

Answer (score 3):

I do agree with RobJohn, but I may have a little more to add. There's [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262920/rate-of-convergence-of-a-single-neuron-perceptron-network) which seems to deal with the same subject, I [suggested](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262920/rate-of-convergence-of-a-single-neuron-perceptron-network#comment804498_262920) the following:

> Theoretical Comp-sci is for research level questions, try Computational Science, Computer Science. Perhaps Cross Validated or DSP too.

I've seen a chapter about neural networks in a book I have. And when I watched some lectures on machine learning, it had a little to do with statistics (and it appears that statistics students have optional lectures on machine learning), hence the suggestions. Try to ask it in their chat or meta before.

Comment: By my reckoning, that question is a generic, applied question about training an ANN, whereas my question is a much more abstract, pure-math kind of question. I did consider posting at CV, and I agree even those other places could bear fruit. However, having posted the question at two sites already, I'm a little reluctant to cross post even more.

Comment: If no one is answering your questions in those site, post it in others to see if someone answers it.